# Alternative to Web Server for Authorization Code

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm integrating Google Drive to our products and my Company wants a solution that does not depends on a web server and easy for the user to grant authorization. Is there an alternative to a web server for get getting the authorization code without user interaction?

Comment: please read more about the oauth topic. conceptually you ask for something impossible.

Comment: @ZigMandel can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: conceptually is not possible. either you ask the user, or use delegation with service accounts and ask the domain admin to approve domain-wide access to a server. why? too broad for this forum but otherwise it would not be secure.

Comment: @ZigMandel what if we ask the user from a java application?

Comment: yes, that too, I guess I shouldnt have said "server" and instead a single point where you store the secret, see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount. Of course the server or app needs to be secured, as anyone with access to the app could reverse-engineer to find the secret.